# Error report of C # groupby using AsQueryable

Tags: c#, asqueryable

```
var commodity = _appDbContext.ArchivesCCommodity.Where(lambda)
          .GroupJoin(_appDbContext.ArchivesCCommoditySpecification, a => a.Code, b => b.Commodity, (a, b) => new { a, b })
          .SelectMany(a => a.b.DefaultIfEmpty(), (a, b) => new { a.a, b })
          .GroupJoin(_appDbContext.ArchivesCSpecificationDetail, a => a.a.a.b.SpecificationDetail, d => d.Code, (a, d) => new { a, d })
          .SelectMany(a => a.d.DefaultIfEmpty(), (a, d) => new
          {
              Commodity = a.a.a.Code,
              CommodityName = a.a.a.Name,
              SpecificationDetailName = d.Name,
              OrderSN = d.OrderSN
          }).AsQueryable().OrderBy(a => a.OrderSN).GroupBy(a => new { a.Commodity, a.CommodityName })
           .Select(a => new
           {
               Commodity = a.Key.Commodity,
               CommodityName = a.Key.CommodityName,
               SpecificationDetailName = string.Join(" - ", a.Select(a => a.SpecificationDetailName)),
               SpecificationDetailTotal = string.Join(" - ", a.Select(a => a.SpecificationDetailName)) == "" ? 0 : a.Count()
           });
```

Where .AsQueryable() will cause an error

```
.AsQueryable()
.OrderBy(a => a.OrderSN)
.GroupBy(a => new { a.Commodity, a.CommodityName })
```

[image]

No error will be reported when changing to AsEnumerable()

```
.ASEnumerable()
.OrderBy(a => a.OrderSN)
.GroupBy(a => new { a.Commodity, a.CommodityName })
```

But I don't want to send this code to the database for the time being, because it will be sent after paging query. I don't know how to deal with it?

**//////////////I pasted my complete code and talked about my actual needs**

Query the code and query the database page by page. For example, only one page and 10 rows of records are checked. Here is OK.

```
            var AA= _appDbContext.ArchivesCCommodity.Where(lambda)
              .GroupJoin(_appDbContext.ArchivesCCommoditySpecification, a => a.Code, b => b.Commodity, (a, b) => new { a, b })
              .SelectMany(a => a.b.DefaultIfEmpty(), (a, b) => new { a.a, b })
              .GroupJoin(_appDbContext.ArchivesCSpecificationDetail, a => a.a.b.SpecificationDetail, d => d.Code, (a, d) => new { a, d })
              .SelectMany(a => a.d.DefaultIfEmpty(), (a, d) => new
              {
                  Commodity = a.a.a.a.a.Code,
                  CommodityName = a.a.a.a.a.Name,
                  SpecificationDetailName = d.Name,
                  OrderSN = d.OrderSN
              });

            PageHealper<object> page = new PageHealper<object>();

            page.Start(pageNum, pageSize);

            page = await page.RestPage(AA);
```

At this time, I grouped and sorted again, and now I found that:

1. It is not to operate the paging query results, but to query all the AA databases.
2. Based on the previous pagination query, the number of rows and page numbers are obtained. Here, the number of rows is changed by grouping and merging.
   That's why I want to put grouping and sorting together, and finally pagination.

```
  var BB = AA.AsEnumerable().OrderBy(a => a.OrderSN).GroupBy(a => new { a.Commodity, a.CommodityName, a.Specification, a.SpecificationName })
               .Select(a => new
               {
                   Commodity = a.Key.Commodity,
                   CommodityName = a.Key.CommodityName,
                   SpecificationDetailName = string.Join(" - ", a.Select(a => a.SpecificationDetailName)),
                   SpecificationDetailTotal = string.Join(" - ", a.Select(a => a.SpecificationDetailName)) == "" ? 0 : a.Count()
               }); ;

            page.Data = BB.ToList<object>();
            return page;
```

Comment: There are very few situations where `.AsQueryable()` is useful. Why do you think it would be useful here?

Comment: Its a little known fact that `GroupBy` in framework has a good change of being done in memory. by the time you call `.AsQueryable()` it may have already hit the database.

Comment: Also, as a small tip, `Commodity = a.a.a.Code,` is not the world's best naming. Good luck remembering in a few days what each of those different `a`s mean.

Comment: Have you ever tried removing all the As... ? Just SelectMany().OrderBy()

Comment: @cheny，Tried, wrong

Comment: @mjwills，I mainly don't know how to simplify a.a.a.xxx. As you said, I can't remember

Comment: @TheGeneral Because pagination query and then grouping will lead to inconsistent page numbers, so I want to solve it together, and then pagination, mainly my database is pagination query, not all of them

Comment: Or SelectMany.ToList().OrderBy()? It will cost some memory if you think it's ok.

Comment: @cheny If I understand correctly, ToList()  and. .ASEnumerable() both mean to the database, so I don't want to do so. Let me rewrite the content and tell you my complete requirements

Comment: Ahh, I see what you meant. Yes, ToList() means the SQL behind will be executed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Checkout this article https://weblogs.asp.net/zeeshanhirani/using-asqueryable-with-linq-to-objects-and-linq-to-sql about what AsQueryable does.

I think you dont really need AsQueryable there... LINQ to SQL does not like something about that query.

It does not like the String.Join(...) because it cannot translate it.

So one thing you can do is put .AsEnumerable() after the GroupBy() this will do everything up to in SQL and everything after in memory.

Ex:

```
var commodity = _appDbContext.ArchivesCCommodity.Where(lambda)
        .GroupJoin(_appDbContext.ArchivesCCommoditySpecification, a => a.Code, b => b.Commodity, (a, b) => new { a, b })
        .SelectMany(a => a.b.DefaultIfEmpty(), (a, b) => new { a.a, b })
        .GroupJoin(_appDbContext.ArchivesCSpecificationDetail, a => a.a.a.b.SpecificationDetail, d => d.Code, (a, d) => new { a, d })
        .SelectMany(a => a.d.DefaultIfEmpty(), (a, d) => new
        {
            Commodity = a.a.a.Code,
            CommodityName = a.a.a.Name,
            SpecificationDetailName = d.Name,
            OrderSN = d.OrderSN
        }).OrderBy(a => a.OrderSN).GroupBy(a => new { a.Commodity, a.CommodityName })
        .AnEnumerable()
        .Select(a => new
        {
            Commodity = a.Key.Commodity,
            CommodityName = a.Key.CommodityName,
            SpecificationDetailName = string.Join(" - ", a.Select(a => a.SpecificationDetailName)),
            SpecificationDetailTotal = string.Join(" - ", a.Select(a => a.SpecificationDetailName)) == "" ? 0 : a.Count()
        });
```

Comment: What I want to get is that the entire query does not arrive at the database, and it will not arrive at the database until the later paging query.

Comment: If you want the query to run later then you could put it later in your code. Or you could separate the query into two parts, one before the AsEnumerable() and one after and dont call AsEnumerable() until you want the query to be compiled and executed against the database then once the query runs against the database, later in your code, add the second part of the query which will do the 'select' in memory.